# Jersey Receive List of Files

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I want to receive a List of Files (just the names on a Nexus Server).
Here is my current Code:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(nexusUser, nexusPassword));
WebResource service = client.resource("http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/linkToRepo
ClientResponse response = service.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);

String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
```

But i just receive the html from the Server. I could parse the HTML but is there any possibility to receive directly the name of the files and the path?

Here a short snippet of the HTML Code received:

```
 <body>
<h1>Index of /repositories/linkToRepo</h1>
<table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Name</th>
    <th>Last Modified</th>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="../">Parent Directory</a></td>
  </tr>
              <tr>
        <td><a href="http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/linkToRepo/1.0/">1.0/</a></td>
        <td>Wed May 27 14:38:37 CEST 2015</td>
        <td align="right">
                          &nbsp;
                      </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
              <tr>
        <td><a href="http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/linktoRepo/maven-metadata.xml">maven-metadata.xml</a></td>
        <td>Wed May 27 14:38:37 CEST 2015</td>
        <td align="right">
                          311
                      </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
```

Kind regards,
SirSandmann

Comment: What is the HTML you receive ? Any server code to share ?

Comment: What happens if you request the URL in a browser?

Comment: Hey, if i request the HTML in a Browser, i get a plain HTML with the files listed which are in the directory.

Comment: What kind of server is this? Is it a Nexus Maven repository frontend?

Comment: Yes, it is. Normal, not the pro version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set the http accept header `Accept` to `application/json; charset=UTF-8` in order to receive something easier to parse. (check out the doc to see how to do it https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/client-api.html#d4e642)

However, you should rather use Nexus Rest API (see the doc https://oss.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/index.html) in order to get what you're interested for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint!
I solved the problem with parsing via jsoup because i have no experience with the nexus rest api.

Here the Code:

```
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(nexusUser, nexusPassword));
        WebResource service = client.resource(repoPath);
        ClientResponse response = service.accept("application/json",
                "UTF-8").get(ClientResponse.class);

        String htmlString = response.getEntity(String.class);
        Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(htmlString);
        Elements elements = doc.select("a[href]");
        return elements;
```